# Twinview nvidia browser spring to left monitor

Tags: nvidia, firefox, twinview

Im using ubuntu 12.4 desktop with nvidia graphic GeForce 8400GS. Using twinview. Since couple of days ago when I double click on top of Firefox or chrome to expand in the right monitor. It springs to the left screen. so now it is impossible for me to have Firefox expanded in left and chrome at right screen or other way around. They both expand only in left screen. 
Other applications are working fine. I can expand them at right or left screen.

I hope somebody can help me with this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem by going to display and disable the sticky edges>apply then enable again sticky edges>apply and after that the problem was solved.